# Подключаем библиотеку nib для работы со stylus. Что и где нужно прописать?

Tags: stylus, node.js, css, препроцессор

Пробую препроцессор [Stylus](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/). Установить, запустить вотчер получилось. Пробую подключить билиотеку [nib](http://visionmedia.github.io/nib/). Установил при помощи npm install nib. В style.styl прописал @import 'nib'. По аналогии с sass/compass ничего не инклюдится :( Судя по всему надо создать что-то вроде конфигурационного файла проекта ноды.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что это за файлы, как они должны называться и где лежать?
Что написать в таком файле, чтобы подключить нужную мне библиотеку?
Что писать в консоли для запуска вотчера в таком случае?

Comment: Скажите вам понравилась библиотека Stylus. Если да то чем?

Comment: Да, понравилась. Во-первых это JS-синтаксис с более привычными конструкциями, по сравнению с руби. Во-вторых отсутствие пробела после символа амперсанда. Можно свободно писать такие конструкции &__child (sass бы разорвал селектор пробелом после амперсанда).
Но мне не понравилась скорость работы. Может я сделал что-то не так, но компилируется оно в десятки раз дольше, чем тот же sass, например.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А вы попробуйте просто склонировать репозиторий https://github.com/visionmedia/nib в папку проекта, получиться к примеру такая структура:

`./` - корень проекта
`./styl/` - файлы `stylus`
`./styl/nib/` - библиотека `nib`

Тогда в файле `./styl/index.styl` пишем 
`@import 'nib/index'`
и все должно заработать ;-)

Comment: Действительно, почему бы и нет :) Работает. Спасибо. Оставим пока так.

Answer (score 1):

Еще, можно установить nib глобально (npm -g install nib), и точно так же подключать в любом проекте (@import 'nib') - в таком случае, не прийдется клонировать в каждый проект :)

Comment: Спасибо. Вроде как это то, что нужно. Только не получается пока. Вот установил. Я так понимаю, что ключ -g означает глобально.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22619948/nid1.jpg
Пробую использовать:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22619948/nid2.jpg

Comment: Глобально вроде установился, хорошо. Удали из проекта если скачан nib, далее, в консоли перейди в каталог с файлом style.styl, и введи "stylus -u nib -w style.styl" (если используешь компилятор стилуса - отключи компиляцию)